# Count rows in table and if greater than 0 show table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a table that gets results from my SQL database and shows them on my html page. I want the table to be hidden until the rows are greater than 0.

I have this to count the number of rows:

```
var oRows = document.getElementById('tableID').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var iRowCount = oRows.length;
```

And this is my table

```
<table border="1" id="tableID">
  <tr>
      <th>Results</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><%response.Write(checker) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Checker is the string from my database.

I want to be able to only show my table when the row count is greater than 0. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: which template engine are you using?

Comment: You could use `document.getElementById('tableID').style.display='none'` and `document.getElementById('tableID').style.display='initial'`, but that's just a cheap hack. If your users disabled JavaScript, the table would still show. I suggest you find out if your template engine can use a switch to hide the table instead of using JavaScript for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manage this on the frontend side, and since you don't seem to be using jQuery:

```
if (iRowCount == 0) {
    document.getElementById("tableID").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: You're right. I am not using jquery. Thanks for your answer it worked great :-)

Answer (score 1):

You ca try this out

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
if (table.rows.length > 0)
   table.style.visibility = "visible";
else
   table.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

OR

```
  var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
    if (table.rows.length > 0)
       table.style.display = 'none';
    else
       table.style.display = 'table';
```

Comment: The visibility has an bad effect ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
 var oTable    = document.getElementById('tableID');
 var oRows     = oTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 var iRowCount = oRows.length;

 // If the length be zero
 if(iRowCount == 0) {
      // Hide the table
      oTable.style.display = 'none';
 } else {
      // show the table
      oTable.style.display = 'initial';
 }
```

Why `initial`? It's browsers default.